# Download database result in a div as pdf. Save as pdf or download pdf on button click

Tags: php, jquery, html, pdf, download

I'm loading two images and two tables from a database based on a dropdown list selection.
I'm using PHP & MySQL.

```
<select name="month" id="month">
<option>Select Month</option>
<option value="Jan">Jan</option>
<option value="Feb">Feb</option>
</select>

<div id="contentDiv">two images and two tables</div>

<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Download" />
```

I want to allow the user to download a PDF file containing only the contents (which are dynamically generated) inside the resulting **DIV** (`contentDiv`). How can I accomplish this? I tried many plugins, but haven't found a suitable one.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to send the contents's of your div to your server to create pdf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sol 1[***.TCPDF***](http://www.tcpdf.org/): Open Source PHP Class for generating PDF documents.

Sol 2 . ***[PrinceXML](http://princexml.com/)***.

It's definitely the best HTML/CSS to PDF converter out there, although it's not free (But hey, your programming is not free either, so if it saves you 10 hours of work, you're home free.)

sol 3. ***[DOMPDF](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf)***

sol 4. ***[HTML2PDF and HTML2PS](http://www.tufat.com/s_html2ps_html2pdf.htm)***:

sol 5. ***[Htmldoc](http://www.easysw.com/htmldoc/)***: